# SVN Merge fails with SVN_IS_VALID_REVNUM

Tags: svn, merge

Having trouble merging a branch with the trunk.

The branch I am trying to merge is a copy of another branch, which branched from the original trunk several revisions ago. The [google search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=SVN_IS_VALID_REVNUM) for the variable returns very little. Is what I am trying to do even feasible?

```
[jeff@jeff prod2.3]# svn merge -r 4723:6643 http://svn.hello.com/svn/repos/trunk/
```

svn: In file 'subversion/libsvn_client/merge.c' line 2711: assertion failed (SVN_IS_VALID_REVNUM( revision_primary_url_deleted))

UPDATE: Solved the issue see answer below.

Comment: Is that right that you are trying to merge made in trunk between specified revisions into branch? Where are you running this command (svn info)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve the issue when I dug deeper into the SVN versions. Turns out the I had already done a previous merge at R5231 and that had something to do with the error. When I merged at that revision it worked fine. Luckily I had written down where that merge occurred because otherwise I would have never been able to find out without digging into commit messages.

```
svn merge -r 5231:6643 http://svn.hello.com/svn/repos/trunk/
```